# Cancel timer in lifecycle callback of singleton bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, timer, ejb, wildfly

I have an Java EE project running Wildfly 10.1 Final.

I am creating some timers programmatically using `javax.ejb.TimerService` like this:

```
timerService.createTimer(new Date(), null);
```

And now, I am trying to cancel those timers the next time the project is deployed, because they are still there every time I re-deploy the project, or restart the server.

I tried to use a `Singleton` `Startup` bean for that, like this:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class TimerKiller {

    @PostConstruct
    public void killTimers() {
        timerService.getAllTimers().forEach(timer -> timer.cancel());
    }

    @Resource
    TimerService timerService;
}
```

But, I get an exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEJB0325: Cannot invoke timer
>   service methods in lifecycle callback of non-singleton beans

This is the last exception in the stack trace (the last Caused By).

I can't seem to understand what does this mean. I tried googling but nothing comes up.

Comment: Why the downvote. It would be nice if people would elaborate why they're downvoting the post before doing so, so people can learn from their mistakes.

Comment: I completely agree on the down vote with no comment - I had it happen to me yesterday :-/

Answer (score 2):

Did you use `javax.ejb.Singleton` or `javax.inject.Singleton`. Make sure you are using `javax.ejb.Singleton`.

You can also use a e.g. `SingleActionTimer` and specify it as non-persistent:

```
TimerConfig tc = new TimerConfig(null, false);
timerService.createSingleActionTimer(new Date(), tc);
```

Comment: I just checked. I used javax.ejb.Singleton. Thanks for the tip for SingleActionTimer